# On iTunes for Mac, download all music from iTunes Match

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match

Is there any way to download all of my iTunes Match music in one go on iTunes OS X?

I've tried selecting all then clicking the little iCloud Button.

I've also tried generating an Automator 'Watch me do' script, but that fails because the iCloud buttons have not been given a namespace selector, meaning the script errors out.

Does anyone know how this could be achieved? I have over 2,000 songs and don't want to click the button individually for each one.

Comment: Have you tried selecting all and then selecting download from the right-click context menu?

Comment: Yes, select all and right-click.

Comment: *facepalm*. I hadn't seen that one.

Comment: Alfo, you get an upvote for trying Automator. @Diago, shouldn't you post that as an answer so this question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To download all your music from iCloud:

- Select all or select the tracks you want to download
- Right click on the selected items
- Click Download

NOTE: iTunes 12.2 does not have a "Download" option.  When you right-click on the selected items you will need to select "Make Available Offline" to download the items from iCloud

Comment: This post was helpful since I tried many times the Select all and right click option. Unless you have your cursor selecting the first item in your iTunes list, the Download option does not appear in the right click menu. You'd think that would be a single selection in the main menu called "Download all items for play offline". That sounds like something a lot of people would want to do to save bandwidth on wireless.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers talk about selecting music in iTunes and then clicking "Download" on the menu. It appears that, in the newest version of iTunes (Aug. 2015), this action has been renamed "Make Available Offline".

Answer (score 0):

could not getting other suggestion to work.  What did work for me was to right click on the playlist and select download.  It then downloads all the tracks on the playlist.  Had to do this on each playlist but i have only have around 10 playlist so didn't take much time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the song menu in itunes.
2. goto Edit, select all.
3. Right click on any song whilst they are all highlighted.
4. Select Download

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) Hold shift to select multiple songs at once and (while holding shift) use the arrow to scroll down highlighting your library of songs; then right click and on the very top selection it will say download; click download and every highlighted song will get downloaded.

Option 2) For purchased songs, go to iTunes store, then on the third box down on the right under your account, redeem etc it will say "purchased". Log into your account first, then it will show all purchased songs. In the bottom right corner it will say "download all". Click it will download history of purchased (minus CDs or internet downloads not via Apple)

Answer (score 0):

I just selected all of the songs I had yet to download and added them to a playlist on my computer, which prompted it to confirm that I wanted to download/make all of the songs available offline, which I did. :)